# Пытаюсь написать мультипоточный сервер на Spring + Hibernate + socket. Ругается якобы на кол-во сокетов открытых

Tags: java, многопоточность, spring, hibernate, jpa

Через Spring подключаю @PersistenceContext EntityManager. По самой стандартной схеме DAO -> Service.
+ TransactionManager.

[image: DAO]
[image: service]

Открываю для каждого нового соединения (Socket) свой поток, где в один из моментов в цикле while(true) постоянно запрашиваю данные из БД.

[image: thread]

Чтобы получить самые новые сообщение. В следствии чего в определенный момент вылетает такая вот ошибка, молл кол-во соединений превышено. Что естественно с 2 соединений не могло произойти.

Почему такое появляется?
Падает он спустя некоторое время такого великолепного цикла. Полагаю где-то просто не закрываются connection и они накапливаются. Но честно говоря не очень понимаю где бы это могло быть.

[image: error]

connection pool[image: connection pool]

И в целом, касательно подхода. Нормально ли так делать?

Есть правда еще один момент. В силу того, что потоки созаются в runtime. Сервисы беруться вот так,но думаю это не сильно важно
[image: getBean]

Comment: у вас объявлен transactional manager? Если нет, то думают стоит подключить - https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html. Без него транзакции не будут работать, следовательно не будут закрываться соединения

Comment: Да, объявлен. Вот это меня и смущает. По идеи его наличие должно решить эту проблему. Решил сделаю через чистый Hibernate, сам пропишу транзакции